# How to determine the axis of rotation from a set of point clouds

Tags: c++, rotation, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a number of point clouds taken from an kinect-like instrument that is mounted on a tripod and then rotated. How do I determine the rotation axis accurately? I'm using c++ PCL and Eigen.

I can match the point clouds together with ICP and run a global registration (SLAM or ELCH) to get combined point cloud but for a number of reasons I would like to be able to determine the axis accurately and force the registrations to respect this rotation.

One issue that is related to this problem is the origin of my instrument. I can measure the distance to the rotation axis from the external dimensions of the device fairly accurately but I don't know exactly where is the origin in relation the extremities of the device. Solving this issue could help me to locate the origin too.

There are two methods that I'm considering.

One is to take the transformation matrices of the registered point clouds and extract the translation vectors that represent the locations where the transformation would project the internal origin in the current position. To the set of points acquired this way I could try to fit a circle and the center point would represent a vector from the origin to the rotation axis and the normal direction of the circle would be the direction of the axis.

The other option is to determine the rotation axis directly from any single rotation matrix, but the vector to the rotation axis seems volatile.

Any better solutions or insights on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the major axis oft the tensor of inertia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia.

All points  can be considered to have the same mass. Then you can use the Steiner approach.

Comment: I've been thinking about this. Not sure if I'm missing something here. The parallel axis theorem is about the center of mass, no? My points are not uniformly distributed and do not necessarily cover the whole circle anyways, so their center of mass will not align with the axis of rotation. I think I need some restrictions for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to place a chessboard at ~1 [m]. Use the kinect camera to make images for different rotations, where the hole chessboard is still visible. Fit the chessboard using [OpenCV](http://sourishghosh.com/2016/stereo-calibration-cpp-opencv/).

The goal is to find the xyz coordinates of the chessboard for the different orientations. Use your camera api functions to determine the xyz coordinates of the chessboard or do the following:

- Determine camera intrinsics of camera 1 and 2. (use both color and IR images for kinect).
- Determine camera extrinsics (camera 2 [R,t] wrt camera 1)
- Use the values to calculate projection matrices 
  [image: projection matrices equations]
- Use the projection matrices to [triangulate the points](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints) of the chessboard to get coordinates in [X,Y,Z] wrt camera1 coordinate system.

Each group of chessboard points is called [x_i]. Now we can write the equation:

[image: Transformation equation]

**Update:**
This equation can be solved with a non-linear solver, I used [ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/).

```
#include "ceres/ceres.h"
#include "ceres/rotation.h"
#include "glog/logging.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "csv.h"
#include "Eigen/Eigen"

using ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction;
using ceres::CostFunction;
using ceres::Problem;
using ceres::Solver;
using ceres::Solve;

struct AxisRotationError {
    AxisRotationError(double observed_x0, double observed_y0, double observed_z0, double observed_x1, double observed_y1, double observed_z1)
        : observed_x0(observed_x0), observed_y0(observed_y0), observed_z0(observed_z0), observed_x1(observed_x1), observed_y1(observed_y1), observed_z1(observed_z1) {}

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* const axis, const T* const angle, const T* const trans, T* residuals) const {
    //bool operator()(const T* const axis, const T* const trans, T* residuals) const {
        // Normalize axis
        T a[3];
        T k = axis[0] * axis[0] + axis[1] * axis[1] + axis[2] * axis[2];
        a[0] = axis[0] / sqrt(k);
        a[1] = axis[1] / sqrt(k);
        a[2] = axis[2] / sqrt(k);

        // Define quaternion from axis and angle. Convert angle to radians
        T pi = T(3.14159265359);
        //T angle[1] = {T(10.0)};
        T quaternion[4] = { cos((angle[0]*pi / 180.0) / 2.0), 
            a[0] * sin((angle[0] * pi / 180.0) / 2.0),
            a[1] * sin((angle[0] * pi / 180.0) / 2.0),
            a[2] * sin((angle[0] * pi / 180.0) / 2.0) };

        // Define transformation
        T t[3] = { trans[0], trans[1], trans[2] };

        // Calculate predicted positions
        T observedPoint0[3] = { T(observed_x0), T(observed_y0), T(observed_z0)};
        T point[3]; point[0] = observedPoint0[0] - t[0]; point[1] = observedPoint0[1] - t[1]; point[2] = observedPoint0[2] - t[2];
        T rotatedPoint[3];
        ceres::QuaternionRotatePoint(quaternion, point, rotatedPoint);
        T predicted_x = rotatedPoint[0] + t[0];
        T predicted_y = rotatedPoint[1] + t[1];
        T predicted_z = rotatedPoint[2] + t[2];

        // The error is the difference between the predicted and observed position.
        residuals[0] = predicted_x - T(observed_x1);
        residuals[1] = predicted_y - T(observed_y1);
        residuals[2] = predicted_z - T(observed_z1);
        return true;
    }

    // Factory to hide the construction of the CostFunction object from
    // the client code.
    static ceres::CostFunction* Create(const double observed_x0, const double observed_y0, const double observed_z0, 
                                       const double observed_x1, const double observed_y1, const double observed_z1) {
        // Define AutoDiffCostFunction. <AxisRotationError, #residuals, #dim axis, #dim angle, #dim trans
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<AxisRotationError, 3, 3, 1,3>(
            new AxisRotationError(observed_x0, observed_y0, observed_z0, observed_x1, observed_y1, observed_z1)));
    }

    double observed_x0;
    double observed_y0;
    double observed_z0;
    double observed_x1;
    double observed_y1;
    double observed_z1;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

  // Load points.csv into cv::Mat's
  // 216 rows with (x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1)
  // [x1,y1,z1] = R* [x0-tx,y0-ty,z0-tz] + [tx,ty,tz]
  // The xyz coordinates are points on a chessboard, where the chessboard 
  // is rotated for 4x. Each chessboard has 54 xyz points. So 4x 54,
  // gives the 216 rows of observations.
  // The chessboard is located at [0,0,1], as the camera_0 is located
  // at [-0.1,0,0], the t should become [0.1,0,1.0].
  // The chessboard is rotated around axis [0.0,1.0,0.0]
  io::CSVReader<6> in("points.csv");
  float x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1;

  // The observations
  cv::Mat x_0(216, 3, CV_32F);
  cv::Mat x_1(216, 3, CV_32F);
  for (int rowNr = 0; rowNr < 216; rowNr++){
      if (in.read_row(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1))
      {
          x_0.at<float>(rowNr, 0) = x0;
          x_0.at<float>(rowNr, 1) = y0;
          x_0.at<float>(rowNr, 2) = z0;
          x_1.at<float>(rowNr, 0) = x1;
          x_1.at<float>(rowNr, 1) = y1;
          x_1.at<float>(rowNr, 2) = z1;
      }
  }

  std::cout << x_0(cv::Rect(0, 0, 2, 5)) << std::endl;

  // The variable to solve for with its initial value. It will be
  // mutated in place by the solver.
  int numObservations = 216;
  double axis[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
  double* pAxis; pAxis = axis;
  double angles[4] = { 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0 };
  double* pAngles; pAngles = angles;
  double t[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,};
  double* pT; pT = t;
  bool FLAGS_robustify = true;

  // Build the problem.
  Problem problem;

  // Set up the only cost function (also known as residual). This uses
  // auto-differentiation to obtain the derivative (jacobian).
  for (int i = 0; i < numObservations; ++i) {
      ceres::CostFunction* cost_function =
          AxisRotationError::Create(
          x_0.at<float>(i, 0), x_0.at<float>(i, 1), x_0.at<float>(i, 2),
          x_1.at<float>(i, 0), x_1.at<float>(i, 1), x_1.at<float>(i, 2));
      //std::cout << "pAngles: " << pAngles[i / 54] << ", " << i / 54 << std::endl;
      ceres::LossFunction* loss_function = FLAGS_robustify ? new ceres::HuberLoss(0.001) : NULL;
      //ceres::LossFunction* loss_function = FLAGS_robustify ? new ceres::CauchyLoss(0.002) : NULL;
      problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function, loss_function, pAxis, &pAngles[i/54], pT);
      //problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function, loss_function, pAxis, pT);
  }

  // Run the solver!
  ceres::Solver::Options options;
  options.linear_solver_type = ceres::DENSE_SCHUR;
  //options.linear_solver_type = ceres::DENSE_QR;
  options.minimizer_progress_to_stdout = true;
  options.trust_region_strategy_type = ceres::LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT;
  options.num_threads = 4;
  options.use_nonmonotonic_steps = false;
  ceres::Solver::Summary summary;
  ceres::Solve(options, &problem, &summary);
  //std::cout << summary.FullReport() << "\n";
  std::cout << summary.BriefReport() << "\n";

  // Normalize axis
  double k = axis[0] * axis[0] + axis[1] * axis[1] + axis[2] * axis[2];
  axis[0] = axis[0] / sqrt(k);
  axis[1] = axis[1] / sqrt(k);
  axis[2] = axis[2] / sqrt(k);

  // Plot results
  std::cout << "axis: [ " << axis[0] << "," << axis[1] << "," << axis[2] << " ]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "t: [ " << t[0] << "," << t[1] << "," << t[2] << " ]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "angles: [ " << angles[0] << "," << angles[1] << "," << angles[2] << "," << angles[3] << " ]" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result I've got:

```
iter      cost      cost_change  |gradient|   |step|    tr_ratio  tr_radius  ls_iter  iter_time  total_time
   0  3.632073e-003    0.00e+000    3.76e-002   0.00e+000   0.00e+000  1.00e+004        0    4.30e-004    7.57e-004
   1  3.787837e-005    3.59e-003    2.10e-003   1.17e-001   1.92e+000  3.00e+004        1    7.43e-004    8.55e-003
   2  3.756202e-005    3.16e-007    1.73e-003   5.49e-001   1.61e-001  2.29e+004        1    5.35e-004    1.13e-002
   3  3.589147e-005    1.67e-006    2.90e-004   9.19e-002   9.77e-001  6.87e+004        1    5.96e-004    1.46e-002
   4  3.584281e-005    4.87e-008    1.38e-005   2.70e-002   1.00e+000  2.06e+005        1    4.99e-004    1.73e-002
   5  3.584268e-005    1.35e-010    1.02e-007   1.63e-003   1.01e+000  6.18e+005        1    6.32e-004    2.01e-002
Ceres Solver Report: Iterations: 6, Initial cost: 3.632073e-003, Final cost: 3.584268e-005, Termination: CONVERGENCE
axis: [ 0.00119037,0.999908,-0.0134817 ]
t: [ 0.0993185,-0.0080394,1.00236 ]
angles: [ 9.90614,9.94415,9.93216,10.1119 ]
```

The angles result is quite nice 10 degrees. These can even be fixed for my case, as I know the rotation very accurately from my rotation stage. There is a small difference in the t and axis. This is cause by inaccuracies in my virtual stereoCamera simulation. My chessboard squares are not exactly square and the dimensions are also a little off....

My simulation scripts, images, results: [blender_simulation.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgrld46lf1uvzi2/Blender_simulation.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I'm working on the similar problem, but my camera is stationary and the chessboard is on a rotation stage. I would like to find the axis of the rotation stage in camera CS. I still need to solve the equation to find R,t.
So if you have any ideas on this, please share and we can add it to this topic.

Comment: Great work on formulating the equations. This is equivalent to my situation too, I get the transformation matrices from icp but it's all the same, I think. I know how to get t from the xi = R * ( inv(xi) - t) + t. The real question is how to handle the different t_i since the orientations contain noise and every t_i is unique.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your answer a bit but think of this. Given a 4x4 transformation matrix M from camera coordination to global, axis point t_i can be solved for example by solving the axis direction and dividing the translation to axis-wise component that is invariant to rotation and the rotational component v. Recompile 4x4 transformation matrix M [R3, v',[0,0,0,1]] and take an exponent of M, say M*M . Now [0,0,0], v, and the translation vector v2  from M*M are three points on a circular path of the origin so fit a circle to it, the center is the axis location. The center is also t.

Comment: The axis directional translation component should be zero if in reality you only rotate around an axis. Think of rotating a piece of paper on a table, there should be no vertical component in translation part. With measurements it is typically not, and that might give some information about the reliability of your registration. The axis directional component can be found by taking the dot product of translation vector and unit axis vector and multiplying the unit axis vector by that.

Comment: I don't really follow your idea. First of all, you get an transformation matrix from ICP. But these [R,t] are wrt the CS of the camera. The equation is: x_i = R * x_{i-1} + t. So they are not the R,t which we are looking for. Indeed every t_i and R_i is unique. But all the t_i's can be calculated back to points on a plane in a single CS. Averaging these points and the axis should be quite accurate for a large number of measurements.

Comment: For the other part, could you please clarify with an image and equations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158154/discussion-between-deepfreeze-and-rooscannon).

Answer (score 0):

[image]
THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION BUT CLARIFICATION TO A DISCUSSION ABOUT DEFINING THE ROTATION AXIS BETWEEN TWO POSES

Deepfreeze. Here is an Octave script to demonstrate what we discussed in the chat. I know it might be bad practice to post an answer when not presenting one, but I hope this will give you an insight on what I was trying to explain about the relationship between the translation vector and the point on the rotation axis (t_i in your notation).

```
rotation_axis_unit = [0,0,1]' % parallel to z axis
angle = 1 /180 *pi() % one degree

% a rotaion matrix of one degree rotation
R = [cos(angle) -sin(angle) 0 ; sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 ; 0 0 1 ]; 

% the point around wich to rotate
axis_point = [-10,0,0]' % a point

% just a point used to demonstrate that all points form a circular path
test_point = [10,5,0]';


%containers for plotting
path_origin = zeros(360,3);
path_test_point = zeros(360,3);
path_v = zeros(360,3);

origin = [0,0,0]';

% updating rotation matrix
R_i = R;
M1 = [R,R*-axis_point.+axis_point;[0,0,0,1]];
% go around a full circle
for i=1:360

  % v = the last column of M. Created from axis_point.
  % -axis_point is the vector from axis_point to origin which is being rotated
  % then a correction is applied to center it around the axis point
  v = R_i * -axis_point .+ axis_point;

  % building 4x4 transformation matrix
  M = [R_i, v;[0,0,0,1]];
  % M could also be built M_i = M1 * M_i, rotating the previous M by one degree around axis_point

  % rotatin testing point and saving it
  test_point_i = M * [test_point;1];
  path_test_point(i,:) = test_point_i(1:3,1)';

  % saving the translation part of M
  path_v(i,:) = v';

  % rotating origin point and saving it
  origin_i = test_point_i = M * [origin;1];
  path_origin(i,:) = origin_i(1:3,1)';

  R_i = R * R_i ;

end
figure(1)
% plot test point path, just to show it forms a circular path, center and axis_point
scatter3(path_test_point(:,1), path_test_point(:,2), path_test_point(:,3), 5,'r')
hold on
% plotting origin path, circular, center at axis_point
scatter3(path_origin(:,1), path_origin(:,2), path_origin(:,3), 7,'r')
hold on
% plotting translation vectors, identical to origin path, (if invisible rotate so that you are watching it from z axis direction)
scatter3(path_v(:,1), path_v(:,2), path_v(:,3), 1, 'black');
hold on 

% plots for visual analysis
scatter3(0,0,0,5,'b') % origin
hold on
scatter3(axis_point(1), axis_point(2), axis_point(3), 5, 'g') % axis point, center of the circles
hold on 
scatter3(test_point(1), test_point(2), test_point(3), 5, 'black') % test point origin
hold off

% what does this demonstrate?
% it shows that that the ralationship between a 4x4 
% transformation matrix and axis_angle notation plus point on the rotation axis
% M = [ R, v,; [0,0,0,1]] =  [ R_i , R_i * -c + c; [ 0, 0, 0, 1] ]
% 
% where c equals axis_point ( = perpendicular vector from origin to the axis of rotation )

% pay attention to path_v and path_origin
% they are identical
% path_v was extracted from the 4x4 transformation matrix M
% and path_origin was created by rotating the origin point by M
%--> v = R_i * -.c +.c

% Notice that since M describes a rotation of alpha angles around an 
% axis that goes through c 
% and its translation vector lies on a circle whose center
% is at the rotation_axis and radius is the distance from that
% point to origin ->
%
% M * M will describe a rotation of 2 x alpha angles around the same axis
% Therefore you can easily create more points that lay on that circle  
% by multiplying M by itself and extracting the translation vector
%
% c can then be solved by normal circle fit algorithms.
%------------------------------------------------------------

% CAUTION !!!


% this applies perfectly when the transformation matrices have been created so 
% that the translation is perfectly orthogonal to the rotation axis
% in real world matrices the translation will not be orthogonal

% therefore the points will not travel on a circular path but on a helix and this needs to be
% dealt with when solving the center of rotation.
```